# SQL - Joining two tables without using INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables called authors and titles. I want to list the names of the    publishers that have written children’s books and history books.

Here are the two tables structures:

```
CREATE TABLE authors
  (
  au_id    CHAR(3)     NOT NULL,
  au_fname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  au_lname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  phone    VARCHAR(12)         ,
  address  VARCHAR(20)         ,
  city     VARCHAR(15)         ,
  state    CHAR(2)             ,
  zip      CHAR(5)             ,
  CONSTRAINT pk_authors PRIMARY KEY (au_id)
  )ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO authors VALUES('A01','Sarah','Buchman','718-496-7223','75 West 205 St','Bronx','NY','10468');
INSERT INTO authors VALUES('A02','Wendy','Heydemark','303-986-7020','2922 Baseline Rd','Boulder','CO','80303');
INSERT INTO authors VALUES('A03','Hallie','Hull','415-549-4278','3800 Waldo Ave, #14F','San Francisco','CA','94123');
INSERT INTO authors VALUES('A04','Klee','Hull','415-549-4278','3800 Waldo Ave, #14F','San Francisco','CA','94123');
INSERT INTO authors VALUES('A05','Christian','Kells','212-771-4680','114 Horatio St','New York','NY','10014');
INSERT INTO authors VALUES('A06','','Kellsey','650-836-7128','390 Serra Mall','Palo Alto','CA','94305');
INSERT INTO authors VALUES('A07','Paddy','O''Furniture','941-925-0752','1442 Main St','Sarasota','FL','34236');

CREATE TABLE titles
  (
  title_id   CHAR(3)      NOT NULL,
  title_name VARCHAR(40)  NOT NULL,
  type       VARCHAR(10)          ,
  pub_id     CHAR(3)      NOT NULL,
  pages      INTEGER              ,
  price      DECIMAL(5,2)         ,
  sales      INTEGER              ,
  pubdate    DATE                 ,
  contract   SMALLINT     NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_titles PRIMARY KEY (title_id)
  )ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO titles VALUES('T01','1977!','history','P01',107,21.99,566,DATE '2000-08-01',1);
INSERT INTO titles VALUES('T02','200 Years of German Humor','history','P03',14,19.95,9566,DATE '1998-04-01',1);
INSERT INTO titles VALUES('T03','Ask Your System Administrator','computer','P02',1226,39.95,25667,DATE '2000-09-01',1);
INSERT INTO titles VALUES('T04','But I Did It Unconsciously','psychology','P04',510,12.99,13001,DATE '1999-05-31',1);
INSERT INTO titles VALUES('T05','Exchange of Platitudes','psychology','P04',201,6.95,201440,DATE '2001-01-01',1);
INSERT INTO titles VALUES('T06','How About Never?','biography','P01',473,19.95,11320,DATE '2000-07-31',1);
INSERT INTO titles VALUES('T07','I Blame My Mother','biography','P03',333,23.95,1500200,DATE '1999-10-01',1);
INSERT INTO titles VALUES('T08','Just Wait Until After School','children','P04',86,10.00,4095,DATE '2001-06-01',1);
INSERT INTO titles VALUES('T09','Kiss My Boo-Boo','children','P04',22,13.95,5000,DATE '2002-05-31',1);
INSERT INTO titles VALUES('T10','Not Without My Faberge Egg','biography','P01',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0);
INSERT INTO titles VALUES('T11','Perhaps It''s a Glandular Problem','psychology','P04',826,7.99,94123,DATE '2000-11-30',1);
INSERT INTO titles VALUES('T12','Spontaneous, Not Annoying','biography','P01',507,12.99,100001,DATE '2000-08-31',1);
INSERT INTO titles VALUES('T13','What Are The Civilian Applications?','history','P03',802,29.99,10467,DATE '1999-05-31',1);
```

How can I go about joining the two tables together to get the necessary information?

**I do not want to use inner join.**

I tried, but this returns an empty result.

```
SELECT au_fname, au_lname
FROM authors
WHERE au_id IN
(SELECT pub_id
FROM titles
WHERE type='children'
OR type='history');
```

Comment: What does your data look like?  Are there any pub_id's in titles that have a type of children or history and are there any au_id's that match the pub_ids in that set?

Comment: The query seems to be fine. Unless there is a 3rd table Publications?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I just edited the question with the inserts that I used for these tables.

Comment: You don't have a match between pub_id and au_id according the inserts

Comment: `I want to list the names of the publishers that have written children’s books and history books.` Shouldn't you be selecting from the `publishers` table instead?

Comment: @FelixPamittan Ah, yes. I was looking at the wrong table the whole time. Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you want to use INNER JOIN? The query you posted, which uses the IN clause, is still essentially doing an INNER JOIN under the hood with the subquery. Take a look at the execution plan that's generated.